# VLC plugin out of tree build results in segmentation fault

Tags: plugins, segmentation-fault, vlc

I'm trying to build an 'out of tree' plugin for VLC.

**Computer Specs:** Intel x64 Ubuntu 12.04

**VLC Specs:** VLC media player 2.0.8

To tackle this I

- cloned the VLC git repository
- added my module (just a copy of vmem with some name changes)
- added modules info to the autotools

It worked! I can see my module in VLC when I go to tools->preferences->video->output.

I want to do the same thing 'Out of Tree' where I build the module independent of the VLC tree and copy the generated shared object library to a place where VLC can read it and VLC detects it.

I followed the instructions on here:
[VLC Out of tree compile](https://wiki.videolan.org/OutOfTreeCompile/)

- I copied my 'in tree' module to a new directory
- Wrote a `SConstruct` file to build it based off of the instructions from above as well as the instructions on http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:VLC_Modules_Loading/

**Here is a shortened version of the module:**

```c
#define DOMAIN  "vlc-nysa"
#define _(str)  dgettext(DOMAIN, str)
#define N_(str) (str)
#define MODULE_STRING "nysa-video"

vlc_module_begin()

    /* VLC Uses these to identify the module */
    set_text_domain     (DOMAIN)
    set_description     (N_("Nysa Video Output"                           ))                                     
    set_shortname       (N_("Nysa Video"                                  ))                                     

    set_category        (CAT_VIDEO                                        )                                      
    set_subcategory     (SUBCAT_VIDEO_VOUT                                )                                      
    set_capability      ("vout display", 1                                ) 

    /* Options left out for brevity */

    /* Add Callbacks */
    set_callbacks       (Open, Close                                      )

vlc_module_end()

/* implementation here */
```

**Output**

So people don't have to figure out the scons syntax here is the build output:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o src/nysa_video.os -c -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -O2 -fPIC -fPIC -D__PLUGIN__ -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -DPIC -I/usr/include/vlc -I/usr/include/vlc/plugins -Iinclude src/nysa_video.c
gcc -o build/libnysa_video_plugin.so -Wl,-no-undefined,-z,defs -shared src/nysa_video.os -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lvlc -lvlccore
scons: `install' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
```

**Results**

I do get a file called `libnysa_video_plugin.so` which I copy into `/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output` directory

When I run VLC I get a seg fault:

> VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower (revision 2.0.8a-0-g68cf50b)
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

`dmesg | tail` prints out:

> [141376.468964] vlc[27609]: segfault at 88 ip 00007f06ccd6a4db sp 00007fff029a6310 error 6 in libvlccore.so.5.1.1[7f06ccce4000+db000]

Here is a link to my git repo for this project:
[Nysa Video Git Repo](https://github.com/cospan/vlc_nysa_video_plugin)

To build you need scons and in the base directory:

- to build: `scons`
- to install (installs to `/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output`): `sudo scons install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found there was a bug in my code

```
vlc_module_begin()

/* VLC Uses these to identify the module */
set_text_domain     (DOMAIN)  //THIS SHOULDN'T BE HERE
set_description     (N_("Nysa Video Output"                           ))
```

I felt bad for posting this question when it was simply a bug so I created a git repo that will hopefully help someone looking to build an out of tree plugin for VLC.

[VLC Out of tree Plugin](https://github.com/cospan/vlc_plugin)

There are instructions in the readme